# What is the right way to get both, the admin translation and the frontend value of a multiselect attribute?

Tags: eav, magento2.2.2

I am using the following code to fetch  the admin option value as well as the frontend label from an ID list of vales of a multiselect.

```
    $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', self::ATTRIBUTE_CODE);
    $adminAttribute = clone $attribute;
    $adminAttribute->setStoreId(0);

    $result = [];
    foreach(array_unique($allIds) as $id) {
        $description = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionText($id);
        $fileName = $adminAttribute->getSource()->getOptionText($id);
        $result[$fileName] = $description;
    }
```

In a block on the product list this seems to work, while it does not look clean for me. Anyways, on a product detail page it does not (I get for `$fileName` still the frontend value, not the admin value).

Is there a proper way to do this?

**EDIT** I was thinking about loading the product in Admin store, still I get the non-admin-store value:

```
$adminProduct = $this->_productRepository->getById($product->getId(), false, 0);
$adminProduct->getAttributeText(self::ATTRIBUTE_CODE);
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming your attribute options are coming from a table, and I assume they are because you reference admin and store values, we should be able to call \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table::getAllOptions which depending on the arguments will return the store values or the default (admin) values.

With that you could try something like this:

```
protected function getAttributeOptions($attributeCode) {
    $merged = [];

    $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeCode);
    $source = $attribute->getSource();

    if($source instanceof \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table) {
        $options = $this->optionArrayToHashmap($source->getAllOptions(false, false));
        $adminOptions = $this->optionArrayToHashmap($source->getAllOptions(false, true));

        foreach($adminOptions as $k => $v) {
            $merged[$v] = isset($options[$k]) ? $options[$k] : $v;
        }
    }

    return $merged;
}

protected function optionArrayToHashmap($array) {
    $hashMap = [];

    foreach($array as $option) {
        $hashMap[$option['value']] = (string) $option['label'];
    }

    return $hashMap;
}
```

I can't confirm if this works where you are trying it but it's worth a shot. When I run it against demo store data on the "color" attribute with some values specific to the store view ("Store " prepended) I get the following results:

```
Array (
    [Black] => Store Black
    [Blue] => Store Blue
    [Brown] => Store Brown
    [Gray] => Store Gray
    [Green] => Green
    [Lavender] => Lavender
    [Multi] => Multi
    [Orange] => Orange
    [Purple] => Purple
    [Red] => Red
    [White] => White
    [Yellow] => Yellow
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have just tried this for particular one attribute & it worked for me so I am posting this over here May be this can lead you to something you want to achieve.

```
<?php

class ClassName {

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
    ){
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    }

    public function getAttributes(){
        $attributeCode = 'color';
        $attributeId = 4;
        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeCode);
        $back = $attribute->setStoreId(0)->getSource()->getOptionText($attributeId);
        $front = $attribute->setStoreId(1)->getSource()->getOptionText($attributeId);
        echo "Frontend (User) Value = ".$front." & Backend (Admin) Value = ".$back;
    }
}
```

> We also can achieve this for the all attributes of particular one
>   product via product Id.